# Bind XML nested node Data into Repeater Control in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, repeater

I have consume [openweathermap API](http://openweathermap.org) in xml format. In this XML data node are nested and unordered. I don't know how to bind data in repeater control.

Here is my C# code

```
using System.Net;

    protected void GetWeatherInfo()
    {
        string appId = "API KEY";
        string url = string.Format("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=London&units=metric&mode=xml&cnt=2&APPID={0}", appId);
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            string xmlData= client.DownloadString(url);
            RepDetails.DataSource = xmlData;
            RepDetails.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Coming data from url

```
<weatherdata>
- <location>
        <name>London</name> 
        <type /> 
        <country>GB</country> 
        <timezone /> 
        <location altitude="0" latitude="51.50853" longitude="-0.12574" geobase="geonames" geobaseid="2643743" /> 
  </location>
  <credit /> 
- <meta>
        <lastupdate /> 
        <calctime>0.0278</calctime> 
        <nextupdate /> 
  </meta>
  <sun rise="2015-12-16T08:00:32" set="2015-12-16T15:51:44" /> 
- <forecast>
      - <time day="2015-12-16">
              <symbol number="500" name="light rain" var="10d" /> 
              <precipitation value="1.22" type="rain" /> 
              <windDirection deg="250" code="WSW" name="West-southwest" /> 
              <windSpeed mps="8.54" name="Fresh Breeze" /> 
              <temperature day="13.11" min="12.09" max="13.2" night="12.22" eve="13.02" morn="12.63" /> 
              <pressure unit="hPa" value="1023.73" /> 
              <humidity value="94" unit="%" /> 
              <clouds value="broken clouds" all="64" unit="%" /> 
        </time>
      - <time day="2015-12-17">
              <symbol number="500" name="light rain" var="10d" /> 
              <precipitation value="0.5" type="rain" /> 
              <windDirection deg="199" code="SSW" name="South-southwest" /> 
              <windSpeed mps="7.17" name="Moderate breeze" /> 
              <temperature day="12.86" min="11.16" max="12.87" night="11.16" eve="12.48" morn="11.61" /> 
              <pressure unit="hPa" value="1019.9" /> 
              <humidity value="89" unit="%" /> 
              <clouds value="broken clouds" all="68" unit="%" /> 
       </time>
  </forecast>
  </weatherdata>
```

So, according to my requirement i need sun and time node data but i don't know how to manage relationship between parent and child node data in repeater control.

```
<itemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("sun.rise") %>' Font-Bold="true" />
      <asp:Label ID="lblComment" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("time.temprature.day") %>' />
</itemTemplate>
```

Comment: This should help: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2003/07/04/use-asp-net-data-binding-to-bind-directly-to-xml-sans-dataset/

Comment: When you say `sun.rise` or `time.temprature.day` in your _Eval_ method it means you assigned the exact datasource to your repeater control. If you have not then parse your XML into a datatable or object and then assign it.

Comment: i know this is wrong approach. i am just asking through this type of implementation. basically how can i show  data into aspx page.